# How to capture newly select value from disabled dropdownlist in asp mvc4.0 model property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have project in which there is a form to edit user details. Initially it is disabled but when user search particular user and click edit button everything is enabled. I capture all changed data except dropdown list newly selected value. when user changed data and submit form. on the server end model property for dropdownlist contains old value in place new changed value.

Please help me

```
   <script>

   function Validate(strDecision) {
    //alert("Validate");
    debugger;
    if (strDecision == "EDIT") {
        if ($("#MerchDispName").val() == "" || $("#MerchDispName").val() == null) {
            $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").html("<span>There is no data for editing.</span>");
            $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            debugger;
            $(".ReadOnly").removeAttr("readOnly", "readOnly");
            $(".Disabled").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#Update").show();
            $("#Edit").hide();
            GetDetails();
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        var bFlag = false;
        var iLengthPaymentMode = '@Model.dicPaymentModeVal.Count';
        var iLengthProgramType = '@Model.dicProgramTypeVal.Count';
        var i = 1;
        for (; i <= iLengthPaymentMode; ) {
            if ($("#PaymentCB" + i).is(":checked")) {
                $("#PaymentCB" + i + "hid").val($("#PaymentCB" + i).val());
                 bFlag = true;
             }
             i++;
        }
        if (bFlag == false) {
            $("#PaymentCBmsg").html("<span style='color:Red'>*Please select      at least one payment option.</span>");
            ShowErrorMsg("Please select at least one payment option.");
            $("#PaymentCBmsg").show();
            return false;
        }
        for (; i <= iLengthProgramType; ) {
            if ($("#ProgramCB" + i).is(":checked")) {
                $("#ProgramCB" + i + "hid").val($("#ProgramCB" + i).val());
                bFlag = true;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (bFlag == false) {
            $("#ProgramCBmsg").html("<span style='color:Red'>*Please select at least one program type.</span>");
            ShowErrorMsg("Please select at least one program type.");
            $("#ProgramCBmsg").show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(".Disabled").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(".ReadOnly").attr("readOnly", "readOnly");
            $("#Edit").show();
            $("#Update").hide();
            $("#frmMerchantEDIT").submit();
        }
    }

 }

$(document).ready(function () {
    //debugger;
    var bFlagErrorMessage = '@Model.FlagErrorMessage';
    var bFlagInfoMessage = '@Model.FlagInfoMessage';



    $('#CountryList').on('change', function () {
        debugger;
        var id = this.value;
        //$("#CountryID").val('0');
        $("#CountryID").val(id); // or $(this).val()
    });
    $('#StateList').on('change', function () {
        debugger;
        var id = this.value;
        //$("#StatesID").val('0');
        $("#StatesID").val(id);
        alert(id); // or $(this).val()
    });
    $('#CityList').on('change', function () {
        debugger;
        var id = this.value;
        //$("#CityID").val('0');
        $("#CityID").val(id);
        //alert(this.value); // or $(this).val()
    });
    if (bFlagErrorMessage == 'True') {
        debugger;
        var sErrorMsg = '@Model.ErrorMessage';
        $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").addClass("alert-danger");
        $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").html("<span>" + sErrorMsg + "</span>");
        $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").show();
        $(".ReadOnly").removeAttr("readOnly", "readOnly");
        $(".Disabled").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#Update").show();
        $("#Edit").hide();
    }

    if (bFlagInfoMessage == 'True') {
        debugger;
        var sErrorMsg = '@Model.InfoMessage';
        $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").addClass("alert-success");
        $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").html("<span>" + sErrorMsg + "</span>");
        $("#DivInfoNErrorMsg").show();
    }
    });
    </script>

  @using (Html.BeginForm("EDIT_MERCHANT", "MERCHANT_Permission",  FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmMerchantEDIT", @class = "form-horizontal",   @Role = "form" }))
  {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  //@Html.ValidationSummary()

<div class="logmain_mechant">

    <fieldset>
        <legend class="panel-heading panel-primary" style="font-size:140%">Edit Merchant</legend>
        <div id="DivInfoNErrorMsg" class="alert" hidden="hidden"></div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">                 
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" style="text-decoration:none" data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                        <h2 class="panel-title" style="color:White;font-size:135%">
                          Personal 
                          <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                        </h2>
                    </a>                 
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                     <div class="form-group">                
                        <label for="MerchantName" class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Merchant Name<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MerchantName, new { @id = "MerchantName", @class = "form-control ReadOnly",@onclick= "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MerchantName)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="MerchDispName" class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Merchant Display Name<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MerchantDisplayName, new { @id = "MerchDispName", @class = "form-control", @onclick="hideme()",@placeholder="Merchant Display Name" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MerchantDisplayName)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Address1<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address1, new { @id = "Address1", @class = "form-control ReadOnly", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address1)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-   md-4">Address2:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address2, new { @id = "Address2", @class = "form-control ReadOnly", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address2)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Address3:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address3, new { @id = "Address3", @class = "form-control ReadOnly", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address3)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Country<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, Model.liCountry, new { @id = "CountryList", @class = "form-control Disabled", @onchange = "GetStates()", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CountryID, new { @id="CountryId" })
                          @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CountryName, new { @id = "CountryName", @calss = "form-control" })*@
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryID)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">State<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID, Model.liState, new { @id = "StateList", @class = "form-control Disabled", @onchange = "GetCitis()", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StateID, new { @id = "StateIds" })
                          @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CountryName, new { @id = "CountryName", @calss = "form-control" })*@
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StateName)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">City<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityID, Model.liCity, new { @id = "CityList", @class = "form-control Disabled", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CityID, new { @id = "CityIds" })
                          @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CountryName, new { @id = "CountryName", @calss = "form-control" })*@
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CityName)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">ZipCode<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ZipCode, new { @id = "ZipCode", @class = "form-control ReadOnly", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()", @onkeypress = "return validateZipCode(event);" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ZipCode)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4">PG Merchant Name</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                        @*type="text" name="PayControllerMerName" id="PayControllerMerName" class="form-control" />*@
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.sPGMerchantName, new { @id = "PayControllerMerName", @class = "form-control ReadOnly", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.sPGMerchantName)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">PG Merchant ID<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PayControllerMerID, new { @name = "PayControllerMerID", @id = "PayControllerMerID", @class = "form-control disabled" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PayControllerMerID)
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      @*<div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>*@
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  style="text-decoration:none" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                       <h2 class="panel-title" style="color:White;font-size:135%">
                          Configuration 
                          <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                        </h2>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Merchant Website<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnURL, new { @id = "ReturnURL", @class = "form-control ReadOnly", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReturnURL)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Merchant EmailID<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8"> 
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailID, new { @id = "EmailID", @class = "form-control ReadOnly", @onclick = "ErrorDivHide()" })
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailID)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Program Type<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                         @{
                         var i = 1;
                         foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> k in Model.dicProductType)
                            {
                                var ProductName = "ProgramCB" + i;
                                <span  class="col-sm-offset-1 pull-left">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ProgramCB" value="@k.Key" 
                                checked="@Model.dicProgramTypeVal[k.Key]" id="@ProductName" class="Disabled"
                                onclick="ProgramClick(@ProductName)" /><label for="@ProductName" style="font-weight:normal;">@k.Value</label> </span> 
                                i = i + 1;
                                ProductName = ProductName + "hid";
                             <input type="hidden" id="@ProductName" name="ProgramCB" />
                            }
                          }
                        </div>
                        <div hidden="hidden" id="ProgramCBmsg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Payment Mode<span style="color:Red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                        @{
                         i = 1;
                         foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> k in Model.dicPaymentMode)
                         {
                             var elementName = "PaymentCB" + i;
                                <input type="checkbox" name="PaymentCB"
                                 value="@k.Key" class="Disabled"
                                checked="@Model.dicPaymentModeVal[k.Key]"
                                 id="@elementName" onclick="PaymentClick(@elementName)" />
                            <label for="@elementName" 
                                style="font-weight:lighter;font-size:normal">@k.Value</label>
                             i = i + 1;
                             elementName = elementName + "hid";
                             <input type="hidden" id="@elementName" name="PaymentCB" />
                         }  
                        }
                        </div>
                                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentStateID, new { @id="StatesID"})
                                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentCountryID, new { @id = "CountryID" })
                                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentCityID, new { @id = "CityID" })
                        <div hidden="hidden" id="PaymentCBmsg"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default" id="Button">
                     <span style="color:Red">* Required Fields</span>
                     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" 
                            onclick="Validate('UPDATE')" id="Update">Update</button>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" 
                            onclick="Validate('EDIT')" id="Edit">Edit</button>
                     </div>
              </div>
              <div hidden="hidden">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnClear" onclick="Clear();" style="display: none;">Clear</button>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("EDIT_MERCHANT", "MERCHANT_Permission");" hidden="hidden" id="anClear"></a>


              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    }
Server side code
    if (objMerchant.CurrentCityID != 0 && objMerchant.CurrentCityID !=   objMerchant.CityID)
                    objMerchant.CityID = objMerchant.CurrentCityID;
                if (objMerchant.CurrentStateID != 0 && objMerchant.CurrentStateID != objMerchant.StateID)
                    objMerchant.StateID = objMerchant.CurrentStateID;
                if (objMerchant.CurrentCountryID != 0 && objMerchant.CurrentCountryID != objMerchant.CountryID)
                    objMerchant.CountryID = objMerchant.CurrentCountryID;
```

Comment: How can we guess what is the error is in your code when you don't show it!

Comment: please now look on code. I have shared.

Comment: Why in the world are you not using client side validation. None of those scripts are required at all. You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics.

Comment: thanks for your response. But i dont have time to go through all tutorial can you please help me.

Comment: Sorry to be harsh but your code is nonsense. You need to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

What i think going wrong is the Hidden control. Your code with dropdownlist contains 
@DropDownListFor and @HiddenFor due to which there will be two input with same name and id, and when you are submitting your form. It is taking from the hidden input.

Try to remove the hidden control, because it is not correct to have same id for more than one element in html

I hope this will solve your porblem.